# How can you set the DataContext dynamically in C#-code?

Tags: wpf, datacontext, dynamic

I builded a RibbonGroupBox like this in a C# file:

```
public class TextControl : RibbonGroupBox
{
    public TextControl()
    {
        const double widthOfComboBoxes = 150;

        Binding fontsBinding = new Binding();
        fontsBinding.Source = (TextControlVM)DataContext;
        fontsBinding.Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("Fonts");
        fontsBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        Binding fontSizeBinding = new Binding();
        fontSizeBinding.Source = (TextControlVM)DataContext;
        fontSizeBinding.Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("FontSize");
        fontSizeBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        /* Combobox for the fonts (Arial, etc.) */
        Fluent.ComboBox fontCombo = new Fluent.ComboBox();
        fontCombo.SetBinding(Fluent.ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, fontsBinding);
        fontCombo.SelectedItem = ((TextControlVM)DataContext).DefaultFont;
        fontCombo.Width = widthOfComboBoxes;
        this.AddChild(fontCombo);

        /* Combobox for the fontsizes */
        Fluent.ComboBox fontSizeCombo = new Fluent.ComboBox();
        fontSizeCombo.SetBinding(Fluent.ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, fontSizeBinding);
        fontSizeCombo.SelectedItem = ((TextControlVM)DataContext).DefaultFontSize;
        fontSizeCombo.Width = widthOfComboBoxes;
        this.AddChild(fontSizeCombo);
    }
}
```

I furthermore have a viewmodel (TextControlVM) that contains Properties for Fonts, FontSize, DefaultFont and DefaultFontSize.

When I now use this in another module like this, the DataContext in the above example is null:

```
<Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="Export">
    <TextControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext.TextControl}"/>
</Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
```

When I build the RibbonGroupBox with XAML code everything works fine, so I want to do what XAML automatically does. How can I do that?

Background: I want to use the RibbonGroupBox in several modules. That is why I build it with C#-Code, so that I can access it dynamically. The DataContext will change dependend on the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` is implied in a binding automatically, so you are essentially binding to `RibbonTabItem.DataContext.DataContext.TextControl`, which doesn't exist

To bind to `RibbonTabItem.DataContext.TextControl`, simply leave the extra `DataContext` out of the binding

```
<Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="Export">
    <TextControl DataContext="{Binding TextControl}"/>
</Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Still the DataContext is null.

Comment: @Hauke I would suggest using a tool like Snoop and making sure that your `RibbonTabItem` contains a `DataContext` that has a property called `TextControl` and that is of type `TextControlVM`. The Snoop website is http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just another question: If i just write

    <TextControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext}"/>

Shouldnt the DataContext be not null then?

Comment: @Hauke That would try to bind to `RibbonTabItem.DataContext.DataContext`. Bindings don't usually throw an exception when they encounter an error, such as a value being null, so sometimes they're hard to debug. You can sometimes view binding errors in the Debug window, although I usually just use Snoop to debug my bindings. And if you want to bind to `RibbonTabItem.DataContext`, use `{Binding }` (no path specified)